# Google rewriting description of Singapore site, how can this be optimized?

Tags: seo, google, meta-description

For [this page](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~tianhuat/), when searching using [this](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=tan%20tian%20huat&aq=f&oq=tan%20tian%20huat&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l3j0j62.2173&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), it appears in the description:

> Tian Huat Tan, Etienne Andre, Jun Sun, Yang Liu, Jin Song Dong and
>   Manman Chen. Dynamic Synthesis of Local Time Requirement for Service Composition.

But for [this page](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~sunjun/) when searching using [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=sun%20jun&oq=sun%20jun&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j65j60j0l2.3792&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), it appears in the description:

> Jun SUN. Research Staff. School of Computing National University of
>   Singapore Computing 1 (COM1) ... Email: sunjun (AT) comp.nus.edu.sg
>   ...

Two pages are using tables, but how Google choose the description? And is there any tools that can help optimize the on-page optimization?

Answer (score 0):

The description is called the snippet. It will come from various places depending on the query. Google tries show the most relevant content to the user and will often find text which includes some or all of the keywords searched for.

One place to help them is the meta description tag which is very often used as the snippet.
Sometimes Google uses a description obtained from DMOZ.

[Here are Google's recommendations.](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624)

Comment: @ltai, hi I understand that the description tag, I just didn't figure out how the google decide the description itself without description tag, I am figuring the behavior of google crawler that affects the description it appears.

Comment: @william007 - Please read the Google link. There is no one place where they take and there is a sophisticated algorithm to decide but Google does not publish exact details, it also changes from time to time as well as by search query. The more recommendations from the link you implement, the better Google's snippet can be.

Answer (score 0):

Google choose description via `meta description` tag. If webpage don't have any `meta description` tag, Google automatically take random content from page (here random content is content from starting of web page).

If you want to optimize your webpage, you must have to add `meta description` tab. For example: `<meta name="description" content="some nice content which is appear on Google" />`